# How to avoid unauthorized resource shows to the public in Apache Server, running php?

Tags: php, apache, security

OK, here is the problem, user upload an image, and set the image only for that user, like facebook:

[image]

But, when I copy the url, and send to other:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/48062_4848804102040_906119890_n.jpg

Other people can still access the image. So, this is not really `Only Me` can access the image, in Facebook's case. So, if my image is or file is really important, I may leaked the information. So, how can I avoid this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way: Using php with sessions you store the images *outsite* the public dir and use a php-script to get the image while validating the user.

```
**getimg.php**
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['okToViewImage']) {
  $fn = $_GET['fn'];
  $type = explode('.',$fn);
  header('content-type: image/' . $fn[1]); 
  echo file_get_contents('dirOutsideWWWpubScope/'. $fn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook requires authentication (they check your username and password) and authorization (they check that the image is public, or that the image is for friends of friends and you are a friend of a friend, or etc, etc) before they will give you the link to the image.

To avoid the case that you have described, you need to perform the same auth/authz before serving the image as you do before giving the URL.

Wrapping this sort of protection around an image is usually (in PHP-land) done by storing the image outside the webroot, and then providing access to it only through a PHP script (which performs auth/authz, sets an apropriate content-type header, then reads in the bytes of the image and outputs them to the server for passing to the browser).